# Can I hire a scooter in Spain on a UK provisional license?

Tags: spain, uk-citizens, driving-licenses

I hold a UK provisional drivers licence.

Will I still be able to hire a scooter in San Antonio, Ibiza?

Comment: +1, wonderful question!  Please add if you are travelling on a British passport to Ibiza.

Comment: Have you completed the CBT in the UK?

Answer (score 4):

To drive a vehicle in Spain [you need a valid driving license](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44447) and if your license is not in Spanish or English an international drivers permit. To rent a vehicle you must be allowed to drive it.

A provisional license allows you to learn how to drive under restrictions. For example, you can only drive a car with an instructor next to you and you can not go on motorways. These restrictions show quite clearly this is not a valid drivers license and you can not use it to drive outside of the UK, let alone rent a vehicle.

See https://www.gov.uk/driving-lessons-learning-to-drive/overview for all the rules

Comment: Some countries don't care if the license is 'provisional' or not, e.g. the US.

Comment: @JonathanReez true, but that seems to be more the exception than the rule

Comment: The "only drive with an instructor next to you" restriction only applies to cars (in the UK at least). For 2-wheelers (motorbikes, or scooters like the OP wants), once you've passed the CBT you're free to roam on your own (with restrictions on speed/power/passengers/etc) as a learner

Comment: @Gagravarr edited that in :)

Comment: @JonathanReez any more countries in that list?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how UK provisional driver's liscense, you can rent a moped with the Spanish provisional Tourism vehicle (B-type) driving liscense.

you can always email this company ( the cheapest i've found) that have mopeds from 20€/day and ask them.

http://www.turborentacar.com/en/

Comment: What is the Spanish provisional B license?

Comment: The Green or White card before you get your liscense mailed.

Comment: Ok. But that's a different concept. The British one is a learner's license, not a temporary replacement for a full license as the Spanish document.

Comment: hmm as i said i don't have knowledge on how the english liscense works, so the best would be to directly ask the company that rents the car / scooter. i've seen brittish cars ( yellow plate with UK blue) and a learner's "L" on the rear on salou and similar beach destinations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the provisional licence is only valid in the UK, but check on gov.uk website https://www.gov.uk/ride-motorcycle-moped/overview

and if you're still uncertain you can call the [DVLA](https://www.gov.uk/contact-the-dvla)

Comment: @pnuts but the licence is issued in the UK and they should list that provisional licence is only valid in the UK if you check with them.